# 415 Unsupported Media Type in tomcat

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, tomcat7, jersey-client

I have created a web service if I execute this service from eclipse configured tomcat, then it works properly
But if I execute this service without eclipse tomcat(same tomcat but without eclipse) it says **415 Unsupported Media Type**

Here is my code

```
@Path("{get}")
public class MyClass {
    @POST
    @Path("/token")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getToken(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("password") String password, @FormParam("identity") String identity){
        System.out.println("Service called !!!");
        if(username == null)
            return Response.status(404).entity("username can not be null").build(); 
        if(username != null && username.length() == 0)
            return Response.status(404).entity("username can not be empty").build();    

        if(password == null)
            return Response.status(404).entity("password can not be null").build(); 
        if(password != null && password.length() == 0)
            return Response.status(404).entity("password can not be empty").build();    

        if(identity == null)
            return Response.status(404).entity("identity can not be null").build(); 
        if(identity != null && identity.length() == 0)
            return Response.status(404).entity("identity can not be empty").build();    

        OtherClass obj  =   new OtherClass();

        return Response.status(200)
                .entity(obj.getdata(username, password, identity))
                .build();
    }
```

web.xml is

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Web Service</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Service is called from Advance Rest Client by chrome 
Content-type in request is

> text/html

Comment: What's the result of your code - "obj.getdata(username, password, identity)" ? What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: Why would you make the Content-Type html? You are expecting form parameters. You should set the request Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and actually send form data (i.e. key/value pairs). Are you trying to submit an entire webpage? I don't get why the html Content-Type. Also you should annotate the method with `@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` so there is no confusion.

Comment: Thanks peeskilet, when I change it as you mentioned it does not return any response and I believe it is not getting inside that method because it does not print SOP.

Comment: Problem is this is also working fine incase of eclipse not tomcat but not outside tomcat

Comment: @KarthikR getdata method shall returns map object.

Comment: Okay. Please update the question with the request you send to the service with details like what's the Content-Type  you send and whats the request body etc? This is really needed to find the missing piece.